# Disable router link until the submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a submit button on click of it the router link should be enable to the path of page two from page one, if button is not clicked the router link should be disabled

I've tried by disabling event

Page Two

I have a submit button on click of it the router link should be enable to the path of page two from page one, if button is not clicked the router link should be disabled

Comment: Could you provide some example code ?

Comment: <router-link :to="/page-two"
             :event="disabled ? '' : 'click'">
  Page-Two</router-link>

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `to` value based on the disabled flag.

```
<router-link :to="disabled ? '#' : '/page-two'" :event="disabled ? '' : 'click'"> Page-Two</router-link>
```